# Redshift: Extract date of saturday given week and year

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

How do we extract the date of the Saturday, given the year and week number in Redshift? 
Note: I do not have the date value, only the week number and year.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native concept of a "week number". You could write something like:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', date) + 42 * interval '7 days' + interval '5 days'
```

It's saying to take the given date, truncate it to a Monday, add 42 weeks (substitute your own 'week number'), then move from the Monday to the Saturday. It's not quite right because it depends which day is the first day of the year (eg Sunday). So, it needs some tinkering.

Comment: Thanks John! But i do not have the date at all. Just Year and Week number, such as: 2019, 45. So first i would need to extract the date value from these and then find the corresponding saturday's date of that week. Is there a function to extract the date from week number?

Comment: The `date` above would be, for example, the first day of the year. There is no concept of "week number" in SQL.